# Consume localhost webservice from remote application

Tags: java, php, rest

I have deployed a RESTful java web service on localhost, by using Netbeans 7.2.1. and Glassfish 3.1. Now I need to consume it from a php application that runs on a remote server (http://tsl7.csd.uoc.gr). Unfortunately I have not found a successful way to access it. 
I have tried something like that :

```
  $client = new SoapClient("127.0.0.1:8080/HelloWs/HelloWebService?wsdl"); 
  $result = $client->hello("world"); 
  echo ("result is: ".$result);
```

and also with my public ip (139.162...) but it's not working. 
I have also observed that  this :

```
 $wsdl = file_get_contents('127.0.0.1:8080/HelloWs/HelloWebService?wsdl'); 
 throw new Exception($wsdl, 1);
```

is not working either and returns an empty var. 
Am I doing something wrong in accessing localhost? Could you recommend something step by step, or any relevant tutorials? Sorry for the noob question I am very new to web services.

I would appreciate any detailed guidance :S

Comment: If you have a public IP you have no problems, if not you can use noip or similar

Comment: What exactly is your question. Are you having cross-domain issues with your implementation?  Do you not know how to implement a PHP client? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Have you checked that your router is allowing inbound connections on port 8080? And you need to use your public IP address, 127.0.0.1 is a loopback address that resolves to the same machine you're making the call from (aka, to the PHP host server).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers. @Perception I have done it for my public address too. It didn't work. I also am on the lab's public network, do not know how to check the inbound connections and/or change them..

Comment: On your labs network? Thats a whole different ball game - you have no control over their configuration. To test if they are even letting you do inbound connections, try telnet'ing to your `public-ip:port` combo, from a computer ***outside*** your lab network.

Comment: it fails :S what do i do now? is there any way to publish it on a server too? will it work then?

Answer (score 0):

One way to get at it would be via [SSH tunnelling](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-tunnel.php).

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Had to deploy the service to a remote server. Apparently localhost did not allow inbound connections. Thanks